# Mirror a row from anoter table mysql

Tags: mysql, synchronization

I have to tables in same database

first table is just list of some materials

```
    table materials
| ID | materials_name | 
----------------------|
|  0 |    material1   |
|  1 |    material2   |
```

the second table contains info about the current stock of each material

```
    table stock
| ID | materials_ID | current_stock |
----------------------|---------------|
|  0 |       0        |      10       |
|  1 |       1        |      20       |
```

i want all the rows that are in table: materials, to be also in table stock
and when a data will be added in materials this were updated in stock table too.

to say short, i want materials.ID and stock.materials_ID to be synchronized (mirrored) so that there were no row that is in only one table. i want something like pointer (link) to the row.

Comment: Why are there two tables?

Comment: As Strawberry say, is better just add a `current_stock` field to `materials` table. But if you still want have two table, create a `INSERT/DELETE` trigger for `materials` table

Comment: current stock is not a good idea. i simplified the tables for question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you wanted to separate the 2 tables but one way you could sync them is using [triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Comment: Once upon a time, we would have described this as a poor quality answer.